# What are these insects in my flat and how should I get rid of them?

Tags: pest

I recently moved to a new flat, and I have spotted these types of worms come out at night roaming in the corners and sometimes on the bathroom floor.

I have captured [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gi6Emm1FY1o) for a good look. This one I spotted when I was taking out this box for packaging.

[image]

Comment: See also: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10346/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-get-rid-of-silverfish

Comment: use boric acid to eradicate them, works every time it's done right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are Silverfish, aka Fishmoths or Bristletails. They're insects not worms (note the legs).

They're usually nocturnal unless you find & disturb them in their hiding places.

Their favorite foods are usually starchy cellulose based things like paper & book bindings, carpets, clothes (more likely cotton & wool than artificial fabrics), etc.
Although they are annoying in that they can contaminate food which they manage to get into (for example dried pasta, rice, etc) and cause damage to books, clothing, etc - they do not transmit any disease (at least none which we humans can get).

[Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverfish)

Comment: are they dangerous ?  I am worried about health issue it can lead to !

Comment: No, not dangerous, just annoying.

Comment: What is there that you have not found. I would suggest getting an exterminator.